# Add form input to URL in a new tab

Tags: window.open, window.location

I'm currently using the below to add a user's input to a URL but it opens in the same window. I've tried window.open to get the link to open in a new tab with no luck. I've also tried adding _blank but it appends that to the URL.

```html
<form onsubmit="window.location = 'https://demosite.com/' + input1.value; return false;">
<input id="input1" placeholder="Placeholder" name="input1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try an attribute on the form tag `target='_blank'`? [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Comment: I have but I'm still getting the link opening in the same tab.

Comment: Remove the "onsubmit", replace with `action='https://demosite.com/'` and use `method='GET'`. That should redirect to "`https://demosite.com/?input1=abc`"

Comment: Thanks. That works but the old method didn't add '?input1=' to the URL which breaks the link.

Comment: Then try onsubmit again (remove "action", "method" and "target") with `window.open(url, '_blank')` - where you calculate that url as before

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.open fucntion with target as '_blank'.

try this code

```
enter code here
<form onsubmit="window.open ('https://demosite.com/' ,'_blank'); return false;">
<input id="input1" placeholder="Placeholder" name="input1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

more further you can refer this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Thanks